# Azure Powershell List sub-containers in Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I have a storage account storing blobs in the following container structure:
Name\Year\Month\Day\Hour

I can use `Get-AzureStorageContainer` to get a list of all containers, which returns all the '`Names`', but I need to drill down to the next level and return all '`Year`' containers where name = something.

Does anyone know if this is possible in Azure Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the [List directories in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723628/list-directories-in-a-container)
 question. It discusses in detail how the hierarchy of containers, directories and files work together in Azure Storage Blob accounts.

But to answer your question. If you want to list all files inside the '2018' folder you can run

```
$container = "test"
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accName -StorageAccountKey $accKey
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container -Context $ctx -Prefix 2018
```

If you to drill down further you can add that to the prefix, kinda like

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container -Context $ctx -Prefix 2018/Jan
```

Note, the "folder" is just a prefix to the file. The actual hierachy is quite flat.